# Ionic 2 error: Typescript Error Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target

Tags: angular, typescript, parameters, ionic2

I'm following a tutorial at https://angular-meteor.com/tutorials/whatsapp2/ionic/chats-page for an Ionic 2 application. I receive an error when I add the following code:

```
removeChat(chat: Chat): void {
    this.chats = this.chats.map<Chat[]>(chatsArray => {
        const chatIndex = chatsArray.indexOf(chat);
        chatsArray.splice(chatIndex, 1);

        return chatsArray;
    });
}
```

This function is being called on a click event on the button with class "option-remove"

```
<ion-content class="chats-page-content">
<ion-list class="chats">
    <ion-item-sliding *ngFor="let chat of chats | async">
        <button ion-item class="chat">
            <img class="chat-picture" [src]="chat.picture">
            <div class="chat-info">
                <h2 class="chat-title">{{chat.title}}</h2>

                <span *ngIf="chat.lastMessage" class="last-message">
                    <p *ngIf="chat.lastMessage.type == 'text'" class="last-message-content last-message-content-text">
                        {{chat.lastMessage.content}}
                    </p>
                    <span class="last-message-timestamp">{{chat.lastMessage.createdAt | amCalendar }}</span>
                </span>
            </div>
        </button>
        <ion-item-options class="chat-options">
            <button ion-button color="danger" class="option option-remove" (click)="removeChat(chat)">Remove</button>
        </ion-item-options>
    </ion-item-sliding>
</ion-list>
```

Not sure how accurate the error message is but it seems to have a problem with the line `this.chats.map<Chat[]>(chatsArray => {`.

Comment: `this.chats` is an array of objects or arrays?

Comment: It is an array of objects

Comment: @helenkitt I could not reproduce the issue... make sure you have everything correctly setup like in the link. If you cannot solve, please try and reproduce the issue in a plunker :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`Array.prototype.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) will take a function with object parameter not array.Its not necessary to use in this scenario.
Try:

```
removeChat(chat: Chat): void {
  const chatIndex = this.chats.indexOf(chat);
  this.chats.splice(chatIndex,1);
}
```

Comment: Tried using the above code instead, but this produced two new errors: `Typescript Error
Property 'indexOf' does not exist on type 'Observable<Chat[]>'.` and `Typescript Error
Property 'splice' does not exist on type 'Observable<Chat[]>'.`

Comment: So chats is an observable? In that case you maybe missing `import 'rxjs/add/operator/map'`

Comment: chats is of type Observable<Chat[]> - I have added this import but still the original error message. I already have Observable imported, do I have to import functions individually as well?

Comment: yes.. most of the rxjs functions whihc you use need to be imported explicitely.